# Angular2: Component is not part of any module

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase

I have a working ionic/firebase app and now want to create a web app with the same functionality. I started with this template:  https://github.com/ng-lisbon/angular-firebase-seed. It's Angular 4, Firebase 3.9.

Problem now is that I want to pass data from a parent component to it's child using @input. There are a lot of different tutorials and threads out there regarding this, and yet I don't see what I'm doing wrong in my code.

**Parent HTML**:

```
<app-child [message]="parentMessage"></app-child>
```

**Parent TS**:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-tester',
    templateUrl: './collections.component.html',
    styles: [],
})
export class CollectionComponent implements OnInit {
    userEmail = '';
    alerts = [];
    collections = [];
    childData: any;

  parentMessage = "message from parent"

@Input() message: any;

    constructor(...) { 
        ...
    }

    ngOnInit() {
    }
}
```

**Child HTML:**

```
{{message}}
```

**Child TS:**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-child',
    templateUrl: './collectioninfo.component.html',
    styles: []
})
export class CollectionInfo implements OnInit {
    @Input() message: string;

    constructor(...) { 

    ngOnInit() {}
}
```

I get the error message "Error: Component CollectionComponent is not part of any NgModule or the module has not been imported into your module." As the error suggests I'm messing up something with imports and modules.

**app.module.ts:**

```
import ...
import { CollectionComponent } from 
'./collections/collections.component';
import { CollectionInfo } from './collections/collectioninfo.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ...
    CollectionInfo,
    CollectionComponent
  ],
  imports: [
  ],
  providers: [
    CollectionComponent
  ],
  exports: [
    CollectionComponent
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**collectionsmodule.ts**

```
import ...

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
  ],
  imports: [
  ]
})
export class ProfileModule {}
```

This one is definitely messed up: "export class ProfileModule" obviously doesn't make any sense. I copied it from another component of the seed template. But when I now rename it to "CollectionsModule", it throws another error:

```
Error: Cannot find 'ProfileModule' in 'app/collections/collections.module'
```

Looks like "ProfileModule" is imported somewhere else, but I can't find where. Also not sure if that is really affecting the "is not part of any NgModule"-error.

I read [this very good summary of modules in Angular 4](https://medium.com/@cyrilletuzi/understanding-angular-modules-ngmodule-and-their-scopes-81e4ed6f7407), but still I'm not able to solve my problem.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Would you mind creating a plunker describing the issue ?

Answer (score 5):

You need to add the component under **`declarations`** not inside **`Providers`**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ...
    CollectionInfo,
    CollectionComponent
  ],
  imports: [
  ],
  providers: [
    //remove this CollectionComponent
  ],
  exports: [
    CollectionComponent
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! Unfortunately this doesn't work, I still get the same error message ("Error: Component CollectionComponent is not part of any NgModule or the module has not been imported into your module.")

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had a mistake in my app.routing.ts:

```
const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
    { path: 'collections', loadChildren: 'app/collections/collections.module#ProfileModule' }
]
```

So I tried to load a module that didn't exist in this file any more (think Angular's error messages could have been a bit clearer on that though). Furthermore I had to change my code to

```
const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
    { path: 'collections', component: CollectionComponent }
]
```

Comment: I don't really understand why though. If somebody wants to elaborate on that for future reverence and other readers I'm happy to accept a different answer that explains better.